# How to dynamic inventory from gcp acount using ansible?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ansible, ansible-inventory

Just started with ansible, how do i pull dynamic inventory from my gcp account using ansible?

any kind of example config file will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin for ansible named [gcp_compute](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/inventory/gcp_compute.html) that you could use to discover all your resources from GCP and being shown in Ansible Inventory.

I also found an Ansible [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/scenario_guides/guide_gce.html) which will guide you to implement GCP and Ansible.